# Passing id from this.props.data.id to React ReduxForm

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

My ListItem component was passed data from another component using:

renderData() {

```
 return (
  <ListItem
       key={data.id}
       data={data} />
           )
```

Now in my ListItem component I have access to the data using `this.props.data`. I want to pass the id, `this.props.data.id` to `reduxForm` or my `handleFormSubmit` function.

I tried adding a hidden input field to pass the `id` which didn't work?

```
handleFormSubmit({ id, date }) {

    this.props.post( { id, date })
}
```

And in my render method.....

```
render() {

    const { handleSubmit, fields: { id, date }} = this.props;
     return(
          <div>
          <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
              <input {...id} type="hidden" name="id" value={this.props.data.id} />
              <select className="form-control" {...date} >
          <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
              <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
              <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
              <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
              <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
              <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
              <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
               </select>
            </form>
         </div>
       )
}


export default reduxForm({

     form: 'day', 
     fields: ['id', 'date']
})
```

There must be another way to add the data into my `handleFormSubmit` method that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out..simply had to send the id in my handleFormSubmit helper function and remove id from the form.

```
handleFormSubmit({ date }) {
    const id = this.props.data.id;
    this.props.post( { id, date })
}
```